# Add attribute to one element in mongo array (based on another property of that array item)

Tags: mongodb

I've got a series of mongoDB documents that follow this structure:

```
{
 "_id": "myId",
 "myArray": [
   {"foo": "bar"},
   {"foo": "baz"}
  ]
}
```

Another might look like this:

```
{
 "_id": "myOtherId",
 "myArray": [
   {"foo": "bar"},
   {"foo": "baz"}
  ]
}
```

I need to add a property to any of the array elements where foo=bar only if the id=myOtherId ... in other words, so my second document will look like this (but the first document won't be updated):

```
{
 "_id": "myOtherId",
 "myArray": [
   {"foo": "bar","foot":"bart"},
   {"foo": "baz"}
  ]
}
```

I know that the first argument of my update would be something like this:

```
db.coll.update({$and:[{"_id":"myOtherId"},{"myArray.foo":"bar"}]}, // but what comes in the $set?
```

How do I then compose the `$set` argument so that `{"$foot":"bart"}` is added only where I need it? Is there a way to capture the index value of the array item, or a better way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$and` in this case as there's always an implicit AND between multiple terms in a query object.  You can also use the `$` positional update operator in your `$set` to identity the matched `myArray` element from your query to update:

```javascript
db.coll.update(
    {_id: "myOtherId", "myArray.foo": "bar"}, 
    {$set: {"myArray.$.foot": "bart"}})
```

Comment: Perfect ... positional operator. Thanks for the answer and for teaching me something new.

Comment: It should be just `"myArray.$.foot"` instead of `"myArray.$.$foot"`

Answer (score 0):

Building up on the answer from @JohnnyHK.

In case there are multiple elements in array `myArray` with `{"foo": "bar"}`

```
{
   "_id": "myOtherId",
   "myArray": [
     {"foo": "bar"},
     {"foo": "baz"},
     {"foo": "bar"}
   ]
}
```

and all the matching elements have to be udpated then we need to use arrayFilters with update command.

```
db.coll.update(
    {_id: "myOtherId", "myArray.foo": "bar"}, 
    {$set: {"myArray.$[elem].foot": "bart"}},
    {
      multi: true,
      arrayFilters: [ { "elem.foo": "bar" } ]
    })
```